# How to get super parent div width and set child and parent div widths based on super parent div width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to build one custom directive in angular 4, for resizing div the div.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="super-parent">
    <div class="parent">
        My Div content
        <div class="child" resizer></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And My directive method is:

```
  resizer(offsetX: number) {
    this.width += offsetX;
    this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.style.width = this.width + "px";
  }
```

Here before setting parent node width I am looking to check this width percentage in super parent div width. Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Use Resize Observer For Getting Parent Div width and set the Child Dynamically

FormoreInfo About PollyFill:https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver

> A ResizeObserver is an event handler that receives an array of DOM
>   nodes that have changed based on this handle

First Install polyfill resize Observer

```
npm install resize-observer-polyfill --save-dev
```

Then import into polyfill.ts

```
import * as ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
```

Then use ResizeObserver to set dynamically width to your div

```
var observer = new ResizeObserver( resizeObserverEntries => {
    for (let entry of resizeObserverEntries) {
        const rect = entry.contentRect;
        console.log('Element:', entry.target);
        console.log(`Element size: ${rect.width}px x ${rect.height}px`);
        console.log(`Element padding: ${rect.top}px ; ${rect.left}px`);
    }
});

observer.observe(domElement);
observer.observe(anotherDomElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can achieve this in jQuery like

```
$(this).parent().parent().width();
```

Comment: Yes, do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: `document.body.parentNode; // Returns the <html> element

document.body.parentElement; // Returns the <html> element

document.documentElement.parentNode; // Returns the Document node
document.documentElement.parentElement; // Returns null (<html> does not have a parent ELEMENT node)` This might be helpful. These are pure javascript code

Comment: Try renderer for manipulating DOM , See  :https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/
Otherwise using `this.el.nativeElement` is also fine.

Comment: using pure javascript inside .ts file is also not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with plain java script like below

```
this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode.style.width
```